# I am unable to install bcrypt using npm install. I am able to download every other package except bcrypt . Why is it so?

Tags: node.js, npm-install, bcrypt

PS

```
C:\Users\saalik\Desktop\JS\task manager> npm install --save bcrypt       
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\saalik\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-10T17_07_33_971Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you update your npm to the latest version?

Comment: Thanks. Updating npm solved the problem .

Answer (score 1):

this happens usually because of older version of npm or node, you can read more about this here

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16728

**Solution**

You can resolve this by updating your current npm version by

`npm install -g npm@latest`

take a look here for more about [npm update](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm)

and then

`npm i bcrypt --save`

hope this will help you.